# How to use jenkins pipeline script with UnitTest++ 1.4

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have some C++ code which I build on jenkins. I ran UnitTest++ 1.4 to test the C++ code and this generates some `TestResults*.xml`.

This works nice as long as I configure the jenkins build job using the web frontend:

[image: Jenkins-xUnit-Web]

For a new build job I have to use the jenkins pipeline plugin instead, so I have to write a Jenkinsfile. For evaluating my `TestResults*.xml`, I only found two alternatives:

```
junit 'TestResults*.xml'
step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: 'TestResults*.xml'])
```

But none of them work. Seems that junit xml format is different to UnitTest++ 1.4.

Does anyone know which Jenkinsfile statement is required to correctly use UnitTest++ 1.4 test results xml output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, to use xUnit plugin instead if JUnit plugin. Like this:

```
step([
    $class: 'XUnitBuilder', testTimeMargin: '3000', thresholdMode: 1,
    thresholds: [
        [$class: 'FailedThreshold', failureNewThreshold: '', failureThreshold: '0', unstableNewThreshold: '', unstableThreshold: ''],
        [$class: 'SkippedThreshold', failureNewThreshold: '', failureThreshold: '', unstableNewThreshold: '', unstableThreshold: '']
    ],
    tools: [[
        $class: 'UnitTestJunitHudsonTestType',
        deleteOutputFiles: true,
        failIfNotNew: true,
        pattern: 'result.xml',
        skipNoTestFiles: false,
        stopProcessingIfError: true
    ]]
])
```

Comment: You can also use [Snippet generator](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator) to create code for such steps